# How to return a Tcl dictionary in a script variable?

Tags: tcl, interpreter

I have an SQL callback function after querying the database and I'm then trying to stuff that data into a TCL dictionary so I can capture it in a TCL script.

I have this callback function which gets called for each select and it adds the column as key with it's value. I pass the Tcl_Interp* as the data arg.

```
int callback(void *interp, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    int i = 0; 
    Tcl_Obj *dictPtr = Tcl_NewDictObj();

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        Tcl_Obj *key = Tcl_NewStringObj(azColName[i], -1);
        Tcl_Obj *value = Tcl_NewStringObj((argv[i] ? argv[i] : "null"), -1);

        Tcl_DictObjPut((Tcl_Interp*) interp, dictPtr, key, value);
    }

    return TCL_OK;
}
```

The problem is that when running this command like ...

```
set res [mycommand getrow]
foreach i $res {
    puts "i = $i"
}
```

I see that the callback does get called and the correct key/val's are being added, but the result that gets printed is ...

```
i = 0
```

Am I missing anything here? I'm expecting my key (column) and val's (row) to be listed.

Comment: You're missing a [`Tcl_SetObjResult()`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/SetResult.htm) to actually return the dict.

Comment: Is there not a TCL interface to whatever database you're using?

Comment: There probably is, but I don't want users having to manage the database since database operations are paired with other external ops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a call to `Tcl_SetObjResult`, which is probably best immediately before the function returns `TCL_OK`.

```c
int callback(void *interp, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    int i = 0; 
    Tcl_Obj *dictPtr = Tcl_NewDictObj();

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        Tcl_Obj *key = Tcl_NewStringObj(azColName[i], -1);
        Tcl_Obj *value = Tcl_NewStringObj((argv[i] ? argv[i] : "null"), -1);
        // Should handle refcounts correctly for keys
        Tcl_IncrRefCount(key);
        // Don't need to pass an interp; that's just for errors
        Tcl_DictObjPut(NULL, dictPtr, key, value);
        Tcl_DecrRefCount(key);
    }

    // This is the critical line
    Tcl_SetObjResult((Tcl_Interp*) interp, dictPtr);
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

The reason why `Tcl_DictObjPut` doesn't need an interp here? We can (trivially) prove that it never produces an error; the `dictPtr` argument is always a well-formed dictionary (and unshared, but getting that wrong would cause a panic).

Comment: I fixed the typo in the callback() arg list in the OP. I am passing in interp as the first argument and casting that. It was `void *data`.

Comment: Thanks; that makes sense. I suspected you were doing something like that, but I really wasn't sure. (I've also seen people use global variables for that sort of thing.)